# Second insert not working, but first and third are

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, psycopg2

I have three EXECUTE statements running using `psycopg2`.  The first INSERT is visible after the updates and the third INSERT is visible, but second INSERT is not happening.

`OpenERP` is giving my function an open cursor which I use for all three statements; `OpenERP` then commits after my function returns.  I've tried to catch any exceptions (there are none), I've tried using debugging prints to find clues (none) -- any ideas?  Below are the statements.

works:

```
    cr.execute("""\
        INSERT INTO ir_act_report_xml
            (
              id, header, report_type, type, model, name, report_name,
              create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date,
              auto, multi, attachment_use
               )
        VALUES
            (
              %s, 't', 'pdf', 'ir.actions.report.xml', '%s', '%s', '%s',
              1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
              false, false, false
              )
            """
            % (action_id, model_name, title_name, report_xml_id)
              )
```

does not work, no errors given

```
    cr.execute("""\
        INSERT INTO ir_model_data
            (
            module, name, model, res_id, date_init, date_update,
            create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date,
            noupdate
            )
        VALUES
            (
              '%s', '%s', '%s', %s, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
              1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
              false
              )
            """
            % (module, imd_xml_id, model_name, action_id)
            )
```

works:

```
    cr.execute("""\
        INSERT INTO ir_values
            (
              id, key, key2, value, model, name, res_id,
              create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date
              )
        VALUES
            (
              %s, 'action', 'client_print_multi', 'ir.actions.report.xml,%s', '%s', '%s', 0,
              1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 1, now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
              )
            """
            % (iv_id, action_id, model_name, title_name),
            )
```

All three are processed serially with no intervening commits nor rollbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track down problems like that, check what actually happens on the database.

Set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 before running your SQL statements and check the PostgreSQL log file afterwards. Then you know what statements were actually executed.

Possible explanations for behavior like that:

- The three `INSERT`s are executed on different database sessions.
- The failing statement doesn't even make it to the database, and the exception is caught in Python.
- Your transaction management is different from what you think, and one statement is rolled back.

Comment: The logging suggestion paid off -- turns out OpenERP was deleting my entries later!